# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when trying to connect KTOR via HTTPS

Tags: ktor

I have a ktor (server) instance on VM and Haproxy as reverse proxy service.
Haproxy proxy 443 ssl port to local 8081 port (which ktor starts on).
When i trying to make request via https it returns `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` and in ktor log i have an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: //some not readble symbols
```

But if i use http i works good.
**P.S.**

I don't make any changes in ktor code to use https, think it shoud be on reverse proxy side.

Comment: I think you should configure SSL on the Ktor's side because seems like it tries to parse encrypted data.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman yes, i receive an encrypted data from proxy and ktor can't parse it.
Think i shoud receive raw data or set a ssl config with the same certificates as proxy has.

Comment: Yes. I think you should configure SSL with the same certificates as with proxy.